# Get value of pulumi secret

Tags: python, pulumi

I have a Pulumi (python) script that needs to query a database to get a list of customers. The rest of the setup that it does is based on that list.

I've tried to store the username/password for that list in a pulumi secret with `pulumi config set --secret db_user $USER` and `pulumi config set --secret db_password $PASSWORD` so that they are encrypted in the pulumi stack file. The problem is that when I try to retrieve them, they are Output objects. I think that pulumi does this so that it can track the value and the resource that created it together, but I just need the string values so I can connect to a database and run a query, as in this simplified example:

```py
db_host = pulumi_config.require("db_host")
db_name = pulumi_config.require("db_name")
db_user = pulumi_config.require_secret("db_user")
db_password = pulumi_config.require_secret("db_password")

# psycopg2.connect fails with an error:
# TypeError: <pulumi.output.Output object at 0x10feb3df0> has type Output, but expected one of: bytes, unicode
connection = psycopg2.connect(
                        host = db_host,
                        database = db_name,
                        user = db_user,
                        password = db_password)

cursor = connection.cursor()
    
query = """
SELECT id
FROM customers
WHERE ready = true
ORDER BY id DESC
"""

cursor.execute(query)

customer_ids = []
for record in cursor:
    customer_ids.append(record[0])
```

The code above fails when I try to connect with psycopg2 because it requires a string.

I know that when I use Pulumi libraries that take Pulumi Inputs/Outputs as parameters, the secrets are decrypted just fine. So how can I decrypt these secrets for use with non-Pulumi code?

Comment: For anyone else you can now do `Pulumi.unsecret(secret)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that pulumi does this so that it can track the value and the resource that created it together

The actual reason is because Pulumi needs to *resolve* the value it retrieves from config, and its an eventual operation. Pulumi decrypts the value using the key first, and once that's done it can resolve it.

You're dealing with an Output and like any other Output, you need to resolve the value using an `apply` if you want to interpolate it into a string.

```
connection = Output.all(db_user, db_password) \
    .apply(lambda args: psycopg2.connect(
                        host = db_host,
                        database = db_name,
                        user = args[0],
                        password = args[1]))
    # perform your SQL query here
```

Note, all of the logic you're talking about needs to happen *inside* the `apply`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of doing it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a reference for anyone else who tries to do something like this, the complete solution looked like this:

```py
# Takes a connection object, uses it to perform a query, and then returns a list of customer IDs
def do_query(connection):
    query = """
    SELECT id
    FROM customers
    WHERE ready = true
    ORDER BY id DESC
    """

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)

    customer_ids = []
    for record in cursor:
        customer_ids.append(record[0])

    return customer_ids


# gets a list of customer IDs, wrapped in an Output object.
def get_customer_ids():
    customer_ids = Output.all(db_user, db_password) \
                        .apply(lambda args: do_query(
                                                psycopg2.connect(
                                                    host = db_host,
                                                    database = db_name,
                                                    user = args[0],
                                                    password = args[1])))
    return customer_ids
```

**NOTE:** The list of customer IDs will *still* be wrapped in an Output object, so when you want to use it, you will need to do something like this:

```py
def create_connector_for_customers(customer_ids):
    for customer in customer_ids:
        connector_config = ConnectorConfigArgs(
                               # Use customer_id to set up connector
                                    )
        destination_schema = ConnectorDestinationSchemaArgs(
                               # Use customer_id to set up connector
                                )

# The customer ID list is wrapped in an Output, it can only be accessed within an `apply`
customer_list = get_customer_ids()
customer_list.apply(lambda customer_ids: create_connector_for_customers(customer_ids))
```